# Why does Atom/OSX "change" network files on open?

Tags: macos, samba, atom-editor, smb

I'm using OSX with mounted samba shares. When I open a file from one of the samba directories in Atom editor, before I type anything or hit save, the file shows as "Changed" on the network machine, but not on my local computer.

To clarify: If I have a file called `index.html` and a network file server called `smb://myserver`, mounted as a drive in OSX.

If I use `stat -x index.html` on my computer, it might show Access/Modify/Change dates from a week ago. 
If I SSH into `myserver` and run `stat index.html` it shows the same.
Now, if I open index.html in Atom, and check again:

Local computer: `stat -x index.html` - the Access time has changed, but Modify/Change still show a week ago. (As expected)

Via SSH on `myserver`: Access and Change are both updated, but modify still shows a week ago.

What's going on here?

**For a practical example,** if I run a program like `grunt watch` on `myserver`, it detects these false "changes" and starts running build process tasks every time I change tabs or open a new file in Atom.

This doesn't happen with local files, and it doesn't happen with other editors like vi.

Comment: Hi, that seems more like a bug with atom. did you file an issue?

Comment: This question's from a few years ago, and I know Atom has made tons of changes with regard to their file watching (especially just lately, I think). My workflow has changed quite a bit since then, too, so I doubt I could even recreate this issue if it still exists. Maybe I should just delete the question, or can I mark it as "closed" or something?

Comment: More a software bug than a programming issue

Comment: Hi DMack, thank you for you clarifying comment. I think closing would be appropriate.